# Determine U(R[x])

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine $U(\mathbb{R}[x])$.

What I have: If $x$ is a nonzero real number, then $x \cdot \frac{1}{x}$=1. So $x$ has a multiplicative inverse, and both $1$ and $-1$ belong to $x \in$ $U(\mathbb R[x])$. Since $x$ was abitrary, $\mathbb R$\ {$0$} $\subseteq$ $U(\mathbb{R}[x])$.

Comment: Do you mean the group of units of $\mathbb{R}[x]$? The notation is not standard (there isn't really a standard notation for this).

Comment: Yes, it means the group of units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's not a good idea to use $x$ as a real number in the context of $\mathbf R[x]$. I'd either write $\mathbf R[X]$ or use $y \in \mathbf R-\{0\}$ instead.

To the missing part: If $p(x) \in \mathbf R[x]$ is any polynomial which is invertible, with inverse, say $q(x) \in \mathbf R[x]$. Then $p(x)q(x) = 1$. 
Looking at the degrees we have 
$$ 0 = \deg 1 = \deg (pq) = \deg p + \deg q $$
Hence $\deg p = 0$, that is $p(x) = y$ for some $y \in \mathbf R - \{0\}$. That is $U\bigl(\mathbf R[x]\bigr) \subseteq \mathbf R-\{0\}$.